# Why Spring JPA Bidirectional OneToMany and ManyToOne is not updating the foreign key column?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Hi i am learning Spring JPA using OneToMany and ManyToOne bidirectional relationship, in some example i see OneToMany and ManyToOne relationship when i written in two side, the JPA add a new column as the foreign key column and insert the key value from the Parent table. But when i try mine, the column is always blank. Here is how my code looked like :

Here is my Account.java model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msAccount")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @NotBlank(message = "Not Blank")
    @Size(min = 0, max = 20)
    public String accountId;

    @NotBlank(message = "Not Blank")
    public String accountName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Not Blank")
    @Email(message = "Should be the right email")
    public String accountEmail;

    @NotBlank(message = "Not Blank")
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Minimal 5 char")
    public String accountAddress;

    @NotBlank(message = "Not Blank")
    public String town;

    @NotBlank(message = "Not Blank")
    public String npwp;

    @NotBlank(message = "Not Blank")
    public String phoneNumber;

    public String fax;

    public String remarks;

    @NotNull
    public Date entryTime;

    @NotNull
    public Boolean active;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<Dealer> dealer;

//getter setter skipped

}
```

and here is my Dealer.java model :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msDealer")
public class Dealer {

    @Id
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    @Size(min = 0, max = 20)
    public String dealerId;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    public String dealerName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    @Email(message = "Masukkan Email yang bener")
    public String dealerEmail;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Minimal 5 karakter")
    public String dealerAddress;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Account account;

//getter setter skipped

}
```

and here is my Repository :

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

}
```

and here is my Service :

```
@Service
public class AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public Account save(Account account) {
        return accountRepository.save(account);
    }

}
```

and here is my controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/account")
public class AccountController {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private final int ROW_PER_PAGE = 10;

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @PostMapping("/new")
    public ResponseEntity<Account> addAccount(@Valid @RequestBody Account account) {
        try {
            Account newAccount = accountService.save(account);
            return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/account/" + newAccount.getAccountId()))
                    .body(account);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }

}
```

then i post the JSON into my save endpoint :

```
{
  "accountId": "USA001",
  "accountName": "string",
  "accountEmail": "string",
  "accountAddress": "string",
  "town": "string",
  "npwp": "string",
  "phoneNumber": "string",
  "fax": "string",
  "remarks": "string",
  "entryTime": "2020-04-07T15:01:29.404Z",
  "active": true,
  "dealer": [
    {
      "dealerId": "MMO001",
      "dealerName": "string",
      "dealerEmail": "string",
      "dealerAddress": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

and when i save it the hibernate that showed up in my terminal looked inserting query into that 2 table, but when i check my database table (which is postgresql) i found there is a field "account_account_id" that is null, what did i miss here?

i want the Hibernate run sql like this :

```
insert into account (account_id, account_name, ...etc)
values ('USA001', 1)

insert into dealer (account_account_id, dealer_name, dealer_id, ...etc)
values ('USA001', 'New dealer 1', 'MMO001')
```

Here is my UPDATED Model after some try :

my Account.java
I delete *cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msAccount")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    @Size(min = 0, max = 20)
    public String accountId;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    public String accountName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    @Email(message = "Masukkan Email yang bener")
    public String accountEmail;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Minimal 5 karakter")
    public String accountAddress;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    public String town;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    public String npwp;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    public String phoneNumber;

    public String fax;

    public String remarks;

    @NotNull
    public Date entryTime;

    @NotNull
    public Boolean active;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="account")
    // @JoinColumn(name = "accountId")
    public List<Dealer> dealer;

//getter setter skipped

}
```

and here is my Dealer.java. Added @JoinColumn :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "msDealer")
public class Dealer {

    @Id
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    @Size(min = 0, max = 20)
    public String dealerId;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    public String dealerName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    @Email(message = "Masukkan Email yang bener")
    public String dealerEmail;

    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    @Size(min = 5, message = "Minimal 5 karakter")
    public String dealerAddress;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    public Account account;

//getter setter skipped

}
```

now the error is getting weird, i got this error when i save the JSON data

```
> "Unable to find com.api.b2b.Model.Dealer with id MMO001; nested
> exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find
> com.api.b2b.Model.Dealer with id MMO001"
```

in some tutorial it worked, but mine is not, what did i do wrong?

here is my github repo : https://github.com/Fly-Away/LearningSpring

Comment: JFYI: If you modify the ORM you should either recreate the database (to get updated correctly) or if it is not possible update it manually. Otherwise you will see deprecated tables/columns in your database.

Comment: yes, i use spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create to recreate the table everytime i reload my project

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing the `@JoinColumn` on the child side:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ms_dealer")
public class Dealer {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_account_id")
    public Account account;

    // other fields

}
```

You have used `mappedBy` on the parent side, but there is no mapping on the child side. You need to indicate, that the `Dealer` is the relationship owner - it has the foreign key.

Edit: if you're persisting (not merging) the `Account` entity, together with its children, you should not pass ids of child entities. (Actually passing any ids upon persist is a code smell and most probably a performance killer.) The json used should look like:

```
{
  "accountName": "string",
  "accountEmail": "string",
  "accountAddress": "string",
  "town": "string",
  "npwp": "string",
  "phoneNumber": "string",
  "fax": "string",
  "remarks": "string",
  "entryTime": "2020-04-07T15:01:29.404Z",
  "active": true,
  "dealer": [
    {
      "dealerName": "string",
      "dealerEmail": "string",
      "dealerAddress": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Before saving both-side synchronization might also be needed:

```
account.getDealer().forEach(d -> d.setAccount(account));
```

Edit:

From `Author` edits must cascade to child:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
public List<Dealer> dealer;
```

You might also add `@JsonIgnore` over `Action` or `List<Dealer>` to avoid stackoverflow on serialization to json.

Comment: @KeVin could you add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on the child side (in `Dealer` class over `Account` in `@ManyToOne` annotation and try again?

Comment: yep, still no luck, the column still empty and the @JoinColumn(name = "account_id") should be @JoinColumn(name = "accountId") right? since my model name is accountId and my db column is account_id, jpa will translate Uppercase to underscore right?

Comment: @KeVin no, it should be the same as in the database, did you check it that way?

Comment: yes, i tried both, the result still the same, my account_id column in ms_dealer is still null

Comment: @KeVin if the table is named `ms_dealer`, then it should be `@Table(name = "msDealer")`. I'm guessing there are bugs like that all over the place

Comment: yes, as u can see in my Dealer.java model, it written @Table(name = "msDealer"), my table name will be ms_dealer. is this what u mean?

Comment: @KeVin sorry, I meant `@Table(name = "ms_dealer")`

Comment: yep, the account_id column still empty :(

Comment: @KeVin I just noticed the column name is `account_account_id`, can you try now?

Comment: the column name in my ms_account table is named account_id, i dunno why it created account_account_id at ms_dealer side, and yes i try it and it didn't worked. I try @JoinColumn in Both side then it worked, but this is so strange, i want to use mappedBy without (@JoinColumn

Comment: @KeVin You want `mappedBy` without `JoinColumn`? What will it be `mappedBy` then?

Comment: it should mappedBy account_id right? since i look at tutorial by in28Minutes, and here is the model https://github.com/in28minutes/getting-started-in-5-steps/blob/master/zzz-restful-web-services-with-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/in28minutes/rest/services/springboot/bean/User.java
he didn't use @JoinColumn and it worked

Comment: hi sorry, i must be wrong, i cannot use mappedBy without @JoinColumn but when i use JoinColumn, and i delete this code cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, it give me error "Unable to find com.api.b2b.Model.Dealer with id USA001; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.api.b2b.Model.Dealer with id MMO001" and if i added that line, the account_id column is null

Comment: @KeVin this means, that what you have in database does not fit to the constraints in the model. You need to clean up the data or persist it using the persistence layer in your application

Comment: my database is empty, i always drop my table and recreate it, with this line spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create at my application.properties. hmm.. can u help with the code for persistance layer?

Comment: i just realize the the error "Unable to find com.api.b2b.Model.Dealer with id USA001; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.api.b2b.Model.Dealer with id MMO001" is the error refer "id" is a column name? i don't have column named "id", why it look into that column?

Comment: yes, it returned as error EntityNotFoundException and in the console, i use Spring boot 2.2.5 and the jpa version is 2.2.5 too

Comment: @KeVin I see, check out my edit, try with changed json

Comment: hmm i tried the JSON, submit without primary key column, all my field in the child returned null, and i check my ms_dealer tabel, it doesn't save the ms_dealer, and i check in my console, it appear the JPQL only execute insert into my "ms_account"

Comment: @KeVin I think you need to synchronize both sides of relationship. Before saving the account, please invoke the following `account.getDealer().forEach(d -> d.setAccount(account));`

Comment: @KeVin also if there is noting in the database, passing id for parent is also not needed. It triggers `merge` instead of `persist`, that's why it might not be cascaded, please remove `accountId` from json;>

Comment: Where i have to put “account.getDealer().forEach(d -> d.setAccount(account));” ? In my service or my controller?

Comment: @KeVin In your service right before `return accountRepository.save(account);`

Comment: hi thank u still being here, i got fever and i think it's covid19 lol, but i am fine. here i am back, and still got the same error when adding that line, i have upload my source code into github, can u help me take look? https://github.com/Fly-Away/LearningSpring

Comment: @KeVin I wish you good health, did you try without any ids in json?

Comment: yes, if i post it without the id (primary key) the child (Dealer entities) have all null value and the hibernate only execute insert into ms_account table, can u try run the project?

Comment: @KeVin what db are you using?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: @KeVin you're not autogenerating ids, place `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` together with `@Id` annotation in every class in your model

Comment: Oh.. is that a must? I need accountId as primary key too, when i try have two id in one entity giving me an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211822/discussion-between-andronicus-and-ke-vin).

Comment: thank u bro, i really appreciate your help, it's so detailed and patient, really helped me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

To save child with parent in the bidirectional relationship set parent in child entity also to sync both side.

Here set `account` reference in `dealer` objects

```
public Account save(Account account) {
    for (Dealer dealer: account.getDealer()) {
        dealer.setAccount(account);
    }
    return accountRepository.save(account);
}
```

**Update:**

But if you want to use Unidirectional relation then remove `Account` relation in `Dealer` Entity. Remove this portion

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Account account;
```

Then update the relation in `Account` table.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
public List<Dealer> dealer;
```

Here we remove `mappedBy` because currently we removed mapping in `Dealer`side and  add `@JoinColumn` to define which column we are using for account refference.

Comment: yes i could do that, but that's manually i have to loop the dealer and set it manually, shouldn't it automatically handled by JPA Hibernate? since i trying the Unidirectional OneToMany Relationship, it automatically update my foreign key column

Comment: @KeVin  you probably have a bidirectional association and that need setting "both sides of the link" correctly.

Comment: @KeVin You are using bothside relation in Entity class so you have to use 
`account.getDealer().forEach(d -> d.setAccount(account));` to make both side sync

Comment: @KeVin I added a solution for unidirectional relation. But it will generate more query than bidirectional mapping

Comment: in that way is solving my issue, but i don't want that way (cuz i am learning and finding out what happend with mappedBy, plus that generate more query which is i trying to avoid it), i have update my code like u said in the line before save, i still got that error, i have upload my source code into github, can u have to take look at it? https://github.com/Fly-Away/LearningSpring

Comment: Currently, you are using an existing dealer entity for that you have to implement hashcode and equals also.

Comment: thank u abinas, yes i miss the loop line, but i still missed @JsonIgnore and cascade type, but i already solved my issue. Thank u

Answer (score 1):

As you said you are learning, I would like to give you a detailed answer so it will be easy for you to understand. What you are missing here is `@JoinColumn`.

**`@JoinColumn` could be used on both sides of the relationship.** The point here is in *physical information duplication* (column name) along with *not optimized SQL query that will produce some additional `UPDATE` statements*.

According to [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/):

Since **many to one are** (almost) always the **owner side** of a bidirectional relationship in the JPA spec, the one to many association is annotated by `@OneToMany(mappedBy=...)`

Understand by basic code example

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="troop")
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk")
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

`Troop` has a bidirectional one to many relationship with `Soldier` through the troop property. You don't have to (must not) define any physical mapping in the `mappedBy` side.

To map a bidirectional one to many, with the **one-to-many side as the owning side**, you have to remove the `mappedBy` element and set the many to one `@JoinColumn` as `insertable` and `updatable` to false. This solution is not optimized and will produce some additional `UPDATE` statements.

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk") //we need to duplicate the physical information
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

Comment below if you have any further questions on the explanation given. :)

Comment: Yes i notice the UPDATE statement which is i want to prevent to use that option, i want to use the option 1, using mappedBy, but when i post my JSON, it won’t insert the “troop_fk” perhaps i missed something when i do saving? Or i miss something in the model?

Comment: I am not able to understand your question properly. Can you please narrow down to issue.

Comment: My issue is when i do insert parent and child as one JSON, with OneToMany using the mappedBy in the parent side and ManyToOne and JoinColumn in the child side, it giving me an error, some said i need to loop and set the child like this "account.getDealer().forEach(d -> d.setAccount(account));" before doing save, i try it and it still not solve my error, i have try another way and it worked, but i curious with the mappedBy way, like the first option u in your answer, mine still not working properly, i already upload my code in github, can u take alook? https://github.com/Fly-Away/LearningSpring

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bidirectional relationship between two entities (here `Account` and `Dealer`) you have to decide which side is the owner of said relationship.
By default the *One*-side is the owner which leads to a Join-Table which is updated when modifying the List.

Since you defined the *mappedBy* property (`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")`) the *Many*-side is the owner of the relationship. This means the `account` column in the `msDealer` Table will hold the foreign key of the `Account` and then Join-Table will not be used anymore. The Join-Table is probably a left over from initializing the database before you added the *mappedBy* definition to the annotation.

Options you have:

1. Let the `Dealer` stay the owner and don't use a Join-Table. If you want to observe side effects in the database look at column `msDealer.account`.
2. Use the `@JoinTable` annotation to enforce the usage of such a table

Comment: can u help me with complete code of the model between 2 table? i try add @JoinTable in my Account.java it still won't update the column, still null

Comment: Do you need the join table? Why do you not want to let the `One`-side be the owner?

Comment: yes i need, hmm i will try, so i delete the @OneToMany tag in my Account model and i defined @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "dealer") in my Dealer model like this? but mappedBy seem not work in (@ManyToOne relation, can u provide me with code of two model?

Comment: oh yes, if i add @JoinColumn in my (@OneToMany side is working, but i still curious with mappedBy, can i make it work with mappedBy and use your number 1 option? i still not get it about "look at colum msDealer.account, where should i look? and can u give me example about usage of (@JoinTable ?

Comment: 1) A JoinColumn implies the the Account is the owner of the relationship. If you add the `mappedBy` to the `@OneToMany` it implies the Dealer ist the owner... you can't have both. Only one side can have the ownership if it is bidirectional. If you want both, you have two independent relations.
2) If you have the `mappedBy="account"` it should create a column in the `msDealer` Table called `account` (hence `msDealer.account`).

Comment: PS: You could enforce a JoinColumn even when the `Many`-side is the owner. But that just requires an additional join on loading. If you don't have realy good reason to do so it's just inferior. It might sound harsh but did you consider to read the documentation?
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations